# Watchdog timer changed router and esp8266 behaviour

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

I am working on a home automation project where Pi is acting as broker and ESP8266-01 are acting as clients using Node-Red interface. The ESP acts differently almost everytime I recycle the power. At first, it produced errors like "ets jan 8,2013 rst cause:2 boot mode (1,6)". After few changes produced errors were "soft wdt reset along with a stack trace". All of this was kind of solved when I added a watchdog timer in my code. However, as soon as I did that, the WiFi.localIP() prints 0.0.0.0. To figure it out I tried assigning a static IP. It was done successfully, now the IP address printed by WiFi.localIP() is 192.168.1.4. But the problem is the web server cannot be accessed on this IP. I tried to ping it and it replied back. When I checked in the router admin panel to verify whether the esp is connected or not. I observed some strange properties. I have attached the screenshot for that.

So the problem is if I don't add watchdog timer the program never runs. If I add the watchdog timer, I get 0.0.0.0 as the ESP's IP. If I assign the IP, it is of no use. I am not sharing any code because this happens with all the sketches even the HelloServer example sketch.

[image: Screenshot of authorised stations list]

Comment: Are you sure that the ESP86 has enough power supplied?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic everyday ESP8266 question rather than an IoT question.  Start by finding a working example for using the ESP8266 in the way you desire.  Note that debugging questions are generally not accepted anywhere in the SE system without code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @snake sanders --> yes i am exactly supplying 3.3V power to the esp. But suggest me the best of all method to supply power.

Comment: Is there any site that *could* help? Maybe https://superuser.com/ ? I am not sure, but would like the OP to get help, not just has his question closed, unanswered

Comment: @Mawg - debugging questions which are poorly stated and don't include code really aren't accepted anywhere in the SE system.

Comment: @RohitMathur take note. Chris is correct (+1). Your best chance is probably https://stackoverflow.com, but you must 1) post code 2) tell what it is supposed to do 3) tell what is going wrong, all with as much detail as possible (help people to help you).  Possibly, it might be better to find a dedicated ESP8266 forum, such as http://www.esp8266.com  As great as S.E is, sometimes a dedicated forum is the best answer (sorry, Joel 'n' Jeff ;-)

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I'll look after these factors before posting anything. You can close this. Thank you so much!!